# Testing Issues on Particular Android Devices for Mobile Website

Tags: android

I am trying to recreate an issue which is only caused on HTC One XL phone running Android 4.2.2. It is a styling issue which can be fixed with CSS. The problem is that the Chrome Developers Tool does not have a profile for HTC One XL phone running Android 4.2.2.

I do not have a real device! How can I test for an issue that only exists on particular phone running a particular Android version?

Answer (score 0):

FInd someone with the device to test a beta or debug info gathering build.  There's three reasons one particular device has issues.

1)Hardware problem.  No emulator will solve this as they won't perfectly emulate hardware.

2)Software bug on this device's framework.  Since each OEM ships their own set of patches, there's no way to know what is actually running, except for having the device.

3)Something weird in the system of an individual user.  Some odd combo of software, hardware, and data. You need that actual phone to fix this, but it generally only effects a handful of users.

But none of these are solvable without access to the device, or a real Eureka moment.  More logging helps, but you'd still need to get those logs which requires a device.

Comment: There has to be a way to emulate that device. I can use GenyMotion but I am looking for a much simpler way.

Comment: You can't.  Genymotion isn't a hardware emulator.  It doesn't emulate all the individual chips of the phone, so it will miss large classes of bugs.  It also doesn't know what patches were shipped with the device (in fact many of those patches may be closed source and not legally shippable if they did know), so it won't emualte the exact OS-  for an HTC it won't have the closed source SENSE ui.  It also won't have close sourced drivers, or closed source radio code.  It couldn't emulate an actual cellular network if it wanted to-  your PC doesn't have the hardware.

Comment: Basically, you can emulate something with close to the same specs, but you can't emulate the actual device.  There will be bugs that are missed.  Getting close will work for some bugs, but far from all.  Your best bet is to grab the actual device.

Comment: I am sorry maybe I should have been clear! I AM able to recreate the issue on GenyMotion running HTC ONE XL Android 4.2.2 device.

Comment: Then what's your question? If you can reproduce it on the emulator it seems like you can debug as normal

Comment: My question is that is there any other way instead of using the GenyMotion.